# Deal with css html div align vertically and horizontally

Tags: css, layout, html

I have this layout:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left">LEFT</div>
<div id="mtop">MIDTOP</div>
<div id="mbotton">MIDBOT</div>
<div id="right">RIGHT</div>
<div id="botton">BOTTON</div>
</div> 

#container {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#left {
    height:100px;
    color:white;
    background-color:blue;
    font-size:20px;
    width:100px;
}
#right {
    height:100px;
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
    font-size:20px;
    width:100px;
}
#botton {
    height:20px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: botton color:white;
    background-color:green;
    font-size:20px;
    width:100%;
}
#mtop {
    height:50px;
    color:white;
    background-color:orange;
    font-size:20px;
    width:100px;
}
#mbotton {
    height:50px;
    color:white;
    background-color:pink;
    font-size:20px;
    width:100px;
}
#left, #right {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle
    }
#mtop, #mbotton {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top
}
```

[Live Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/berable/NNvMp/)

But I need this layout

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2XMm.png)

Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move the `#right` div above the `#mtop` div, then you just need a `float: left` for the `#left` div and a `float: right` for the `#right` div

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">LEFT</div>
    <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
    <div id="mtop">MIDTOP</div>
    <div id="mbotton">MIDBOT</div>
    <div id="botton">BOTTON</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
    float: left;
}
#right {
    float: right;
}
```

You should also remove all those `vertical-align`s and change

```
#container {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

All `div`s will then neatly align at the bottom of the `#container`.

Modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NNvMp/22/)

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your middle divs in a parent div, and give the left, middle and right divs `float: left` so they display next to each other.

CSS for middle div:

```
#middle {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NNvMp/13/).

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `<div>` to contain both `MIDTOP` and `MIDBOT`

Better yet, avoid the Container `<div>` altogether and use a `<table>` with 0 px border.

Comment: Tables are never better, except for tabular data. Tables for layout are a thing from the 90's. you should definitely go for the floating divs!